# php - filter/sanitize QUERY_STRING with REGEX to prevent RFI attack

Tags: php, regex, include, query-string, sanitize

i would like to have a `REGEX` to <del>filter</del>/match the `QUERY_STRING` whenever contains the parameters like theese `php|data|ftp|http|..|/|://` and any other character that can be used for Remote File Inclusion.

Thank's to all for the time:

PS: i know this is better done with htaccess but i need a regex now.

Comment: Other characters are: `a-z`, `0-9` and `%` to only name a few.

Comment: ok, nevermind the filter, i want to match only! i want to match for any possible attemp to inlcude files in the query string like `mysite.com/q=http://evilsite.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent remote file inclusion, you could simply [disable the stream wrappers](http://de.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), e.g.

- `allow_url_include` - this option allows the use of URL-aware fopen wrappers with the following functions: include(), include_once(), require(), require_once().

and for any other URL aware functions

- `disable allow_url_fopen` - This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing URL object like files

If you want to check if the query param is a URL, you can use [parse_url](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
if (parse_url($url) === FALSE) {
```

or use the [`filter_*` functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
```

Comment: [`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php): *"**Note** that the function will only find ASCII URLs to be valid; internationalized domain names (containing non-ASCII characters) will fail."* -- Don't know about `parse_url()`.

Comment: @Gordon: this is a good approach, but this does mean that i need to loop trought each var and check if it is a valid URL? isn't more simple to check for http|ftp ../ and so on?

Comment: @JulieRokk wrapping it into a `foreach` isnt particular difficult, is it? You could also use `array_filter` and pass in `parse_url` as a callback. Personally, I'd go with the ini setting or reconsider the design that requires including query params.

Comment: And that is the reason why whitelisting is better then filtering. Filters tend to forget edge-cases / are often not quite perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Don't, if that's your security, it's likely to break. Whitelist and/or check for existance  of local files before including/requiring anything. Better yet: don't let anyone have any direct influence of what files you include with outside variables.

Comment: Agree. In any case, it would better to match what is allowed, rather than what is not allowed.

Comment: i don't need this cause i want let user include files, i want this to be sure no one can do this so. example i want to prevent anyone to to like this `mysite.com/q=http://evilsite.com`

Comment: @Julie: Change the way your parameters are used within the application, then such a thing can't ever happen.

Comment: @Julie: then just go for the `file_exists` option.

Comment: Because if you _'want let user include files'_, but still want to prevent _'Remote File Inclusion.'_, your simplest and safest way to check whether a string is a path to a _local_ file is just asking the OS whether the file exists.